# MySQL Join 4 tables returning only 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my bad English, I have requirement to get data from mysql 4 table but it only return 1 row.

table 1

col_2 in tabl 1 contain numeric data as reference from Table 2 col_2

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | col_1 | col_2   |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  |   A   |  4      |
| 2  |   B   |  5      |
| 3  |   C   |  6      |
+----+-------+---------+
```

table 2

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | col_1 | col_2   |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  |   A   |  4      |
| 2  |   B   |  5      |
| 3  |   C   |  6      |
| 4  |   C   |  7      |
| 5  |   C   |  8      |
+----+-------+---------+
```

table 3

Table 3 col_1 has numeric value of table 1 id but most of theme will be the same id,
and col_2 has numeric value of id from table 4

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | col_1 | col_2   |
+----+-------+---------+
| 1  |   1   |  1      |
| 2  |   1   |  2      |
| 3  |   1   |  3      |
| 4  |   2   |  4      |
| 5  |   2   |  5      |
| 6  |   4   |  8      |
| 7  |   4   |  1      |
| 8  |   5   |  2      |
| 9  |   5   |  5      |
| 10 |   5   |  8      |
| 11 |   5   |  9      |
| 12 |   5   |  10     |
+----+-------+---------+
```

table 4

```
+----+-------+
| id | col_1 |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   A   |
| 2  |   B   |
| 3  |   C   |
+----+-------+
```

the query I run to get data.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.col_1,
    t2.col_1 as result_0,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t4.col_1) as result
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
    ON t2.col_2 = t1.col_2
LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3
    ON t3.col_1 = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table_4 AS t4
    ON t4.id = t3.col_2
WHERE t1.col_2 > 1
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
```

as you can see table 3 has deferent id from table 1 and table 4,
both table has value so I want query to return me as bellow. it means I want the value from table 4 to be separated by comma.

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | result_1  | result_2  | result_3  |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  |   A       |    A      |    A,B,C  |
| 2  |   B       |    B      |    A,B    |
| 3  |   C       |    C      |    C,B    |  
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**UPDATE:**
as requested here is the fiddle of query.

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3af0af/1
thanks

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Please replace table-formed sample data with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (or create a fiddle).

Comment: make different name in fields can helps you to understand...

Comment: As requested I create SQL fiddle with different column names.

Comment: in the query above "table 2" does not have duplicate values but the fiddle you have created "table 2" has duplicates. if removed the duplicates try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b269/2

Comment: Add "Group By t1.id" to your query.

Comment: @SandeepModak your right, That's typo mistake actually there's no duplicate value, but it worked, if you can post as answer will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fiddle you posted

All you have to do is change your query to :-

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t2.role as result_0,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t4.ct) as result
FROM
    table_one AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_tow AS t2
    ON t2.level = t1.level
 JOIN table_three AS t3                       //CHANGED LEFT JOIN TO JOIN
    ON t3.vid = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table_four AS t4
    ON t4.id = t3.cid
WHERE t1.level > 1
group by t1.id ORDER BY t1.id ASC            //ADDED group by t1.id AND CHANGED ORDER BY t1.id DESC TO ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

Comment: it's working now sometimes my head going out off the road :) but I think there is no problem in ordering as ASC/DESC.

Comment: the Only problem is if there is a value in table one and doesn't has id in table three it wont be displayed at all. here you can check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a2c74/1

Comment: as per your fiddle if you want to show "Silver" from table_one then use "LEFT JOIN table_three AS t3"  and  remove condition WHERE t1.level > 1. But that will also fetch "Zee"

Comment: thanks but there's difference if table_one value has level then condition works else I have to remove it. but thank you it working correct.